# Networkx duplicate edges

Tags: python, networkx

If the same edge is added twice to the `networkx` edge data structure, will it then have two edges between the nodes or still just one? For example, would a spring layout show the nodes converge more with edges `[(a,b),(a,b),(a,b),(a,b)]` than `[(a,b),(a,b)]`? If I want to weight the edge, how would I go about it?

Comment: Can you provide us with simple example code that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Have you tried testing this? This sounds like the kind of thing easily amenable to testing.

Comment: you didn't specify whether you are using a Multigraph or regular Graph/DiGraph... you _can_ add multiple edges to a Multigraph.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can test it pretty quickly, but it only adds them once. Edges and nodes are represented as a dictionaries inside the graph structure, and they are only added if they don't actually exist.

For already existing edges, adding them again has no effect.

Comment: thnks. How does one weight the edge?

Comment: This can be readily obtained from the documentation (http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/weighted_graph.html).

Comment: @orange it can? i read that three times and have no idea how to go from a list of edges to a weighted graph.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Did you look at the code that shows how to weight edges: `G.add_edge('a','b',weight=0.6)`?

Comment: yes... but that's not a list... do i really have to loop through my list?

Comment: @MichaelChirico You could use [add_weighted_edges_from](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_weighted_edges_from.html#add-weighted-edges-from). The edges are given in the format `(from, to, weight)`, e.g: `[(1,2,0.5), (0,2,1.5)]`

Comment: However, the underlying code is indeed looping through edges to add them to the graph. Networkx is a versatile framework, but it is not specially fast for large graphs (it is rather slow as hell once you get to large sized graphs). There is a much faster alternative [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) at the expense of being less intuitive and versatile (unless you are happy writing C++ extensions).

Comment: great! so I assume that repeated node adding is also safe too, right? :)

Answer (score 15):

This answer is a bit late, but for the sake of completeness...

You will need to use Networkx's `MultiGraph` to allow multiple edges between two nodes.

Create your graph:

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
```

Then add your edges using `G.add_edge()`.
You can test that duplicate edges are repeated:

```
for i in G.nodes:
    print(i, G.edges(i))
```

Conversely, if you don't want edges repeated, simply create your graph as:

```
G = nx.Graph()
```

Comment: G = nx.DiGraph(G) work the same way?

Comment: `nx.DiGraph` will ignore repeated edges, too